# how to put the table always in the center using fpdf library?

Tags: php, symfony

this is my code

```
<?php

$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Cell(25, 12, "OBS", 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->SetX(67);
for ($x = 0; $x < 11; $x++) {
    $pdf->Cell(9, 6, 'MAC', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(9, 6, 'CPP', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(9, 6, 'CT', 1, 0, 'C');
}
?>
```

Comment: ....and what is your question? This is not a complete code example to be run

Comment: And this is my comment. So where is your question?

Comment: how to put the table always in the center using fpdf library?

Comment: show us the above code which determines the width of the page